# How can I read a zipped CSV file with KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a number of CSV files saved with pandas as zip files. I'd like to read them into KDB without having to manually unzip them in a terminal beforehand.

It looks like KDB supports compression:
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/file-compression/

But I can't figure out how to get it to decompress it. What I read in looks like the literal zip file.

How do I read a zipped CSV file in KDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named pipes can be used for this purpose

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/named-pipes/

```
q)system"rm -f fifo && mkfifo fifo"
q)system"unzip -p t.zip t.csv > fifo &"
q)trade:flip `sym`time`ex`cond`size`price!"STCCFF"$\:()
q).Q.fps[{`trade insert ("STCCFF";",")0:x}]`:fifo
```